# Library or snippet for getting values from cmd run parameters

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

I'm looking for small library or snippet, which can simply fill my program (c++ with qt) variables with parameters given in command line. What do you recommend?
Eg. `string myVariable = libraryFunction("something");`. Function searches for "-something" key in parameters list and sends its value to my variable.

Comment: Have a look at [Boost Program options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/program_options.html#id2607043) library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Boost Program_options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/program_options.html). Also you mention QT, so [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918353/obtaining-command-line-arguments-in-a-qt-application) might help.

Answer (score 1):

I think the suggestion from others to use the Boost program Options is probably the right choice.

However some alternatives:

[Commandline Option Parser - Glib](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.33/glib-Commandline-option-parser.html)

[TCLAP Templatized C++ Command Line Parser Library](http://tclap.sourceforge.net/)